How do I specify playwright chromium version in azure pipeline
We have a pipeline in azure which runs a set of Playwright tests as part of the process.
This have be working well until a few days ago with the following PowerShell script as part of the pipeline.
npm install 
npx playwright install

This was the working response
Downloading Chromium 125.0.6422.26 (playwright build v1117)[2m from https://playwright.azureedge.net/builds/chromium/1117/chromium-win64.zip[22m

Now suddenly this has changed to this and we get issues
Downloading Chromium 127.0.6533.17 (playwright build v1124)[2m from https://playwright.azureedge.net/builds/chromium/1124/chromium-win64.zip[22m

And version 126 has been skipped. Azure now fails to run the tests because it does not yet support chrome 127. How do I specify a version number?
Even NuGet in VS is only offering version 126 as a update.

Thanks for any advise

By "Azure now fails" - assume that you mean your Azure Pipeline. But there are many variables for this. Is this a self-hosted or microsoft-provided build agent? Windows or Linux?


How do I specify a version number?

You can change your PowerShell script to the following one to specify to use the playwright@1.44.1 version.
npm install 
npx playwright@1.44.1 install

Then it will download the Chromium 125.0.6422.26.


Thanks that works nicely. So a quick question, soon azure will upgrade to the next version of chrome and so I will want to update that line so where did you get that info?
So for example if I wanted to download Chromium 126.x.xxx what version would I insert after playwright@ and were do I find this info please.

Hi @Kev, you can check the release note of playwright here. When each new version of Playwright is released, the release notes will contain the Browser Versions corresponding to this Playwright version.

Just what I needed, many thanks
